# convert string urls to html in R

Tags: html, r, string, tags

I have a simple html table with string urls.

I would like to find every url, and replace it with an html tag of that same url.

for instance, `https://waterdata.usgs.gov/ct/nwis/uv?site_no=01127500&emsp`

would be replaced with `"<a href='https://waterdata.usgs.gov/ct/nwis/uv?site_no=01127500&emsp' target='_blank'>https://waterdata.usgs.gov/ct/nwis/uv?site_no=01127500&emsp</a>"`

How do I do this across the entire document? I've looked into stringr, regex, and have tried using python, but can't figure it out.

below is a sample table:

```
"<div class='scrollableContainer'>
  <table class= id='popup'>
    <tr><td></td><th>STAID&emsp;</th><td>01127500&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>STANAME&emsp;</th><td>YANTIC RIVER AT YANTIC, CT&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>ST&emsp;</th><td>CT&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>HUC&emsp;</th><td>01100003&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>CLASS&emsp;</th><td>7&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>FLOW&emsp;</th><td>  857.0&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>STAGE&emsp;</th><td> 4.86&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>TIME&emsp;</th><td>2020-12-01 10:45:00&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>TIME_UTC&emsp;</th><td>2020-12-01 15:45:00&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>URL&emsp;</th><td>https://waterdata.usgs.gov/ct/nwis/uv?site_no=01127500&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>DATUM&emsp;</th><td>NAD83&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>COUNT&emsp;</th><td> 8vdssDcvSDCs9&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>PERCENTILE&emsp;</th><td>97.19&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>FLOODSTAGE&emsp;</th><td>0&emsp;</td></tr></table></div>"
[2] "<div class='scrollableContainer'><table class= id='popup'><tr><td></td><th>STAID&emsp;</th><td>01578310&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>STANAME&emsp;</th><td>SUSQUEHANNA RIVER AT CONOWINGO, MD&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>ST&emsp;</th><td>MD&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>HUC&emsp;</th><td>02050306&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>CLASS&emsp;</th><td>4&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>FLOW&emsp;</th><td>20100.0&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>STAGE&emsp;</th><td>11.63&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>TIME&emsp;</th><td>2020-12-01 10:30:00&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>TIME_UTC&emsp;</th><td>2020-12-01 15:30:00&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>URL&emsp;</th><td>https://waterdata.usgs.gov/md/nwis/uv?site_no=01578310&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>DATUM&emsp;</th><td>NAD83&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>COUNT&emsp;</th><td> 5vdssDcvSDCs2&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>PERCENTILE&emsp;</th><td>12.43&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>FLOODSTAGE&emsp;</th><td>0&emsp;</td></tr></table></div>"
[3] "<div class='scrollableContainer'><table class= id='popup'><tr><td></td><th>STAID&emsp;</th><td>02035000&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>STANAME&emsp;</th><td>JAMES RIVER AT CARTERSVILLE, VA&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>ST&emsp;</th><td>VA&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>HUC&emsp;</th><td>02080205&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>CLASS&emsp;</th><td>7&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>FLOW&emsp;</th><td>46500.0&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>STAGE&emsp;</th><td>15.70&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>TIME&emsp;</th><td>2020-12-01 10:45:00&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>TIME_UTC&emsp;</th><td>2020-12-01 15:45:00&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>URL&emsp;</th><td>https://waterdata.usgs.gov/va/nwis/uv?site_no=02035000&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>DATUM&emsp;</th><td>NAD83&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>COUNT&emsp;</th><td>121&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>PERCENTILE&emsp;</th><td>97.02&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>FLOODSTAGE&emsp;</th><td>0&emsp;</td></tr></table></div>"vdssDcvSDCs
[4] "<div class='scrollableContainer'><table class= id='popup'><tr><td></td><th>STAID&emsp;</th><td>02198690&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>STANAME&emsp;</th><td>EBENEZER CREEK AT SPRINGFIELD, GA&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>ST&emsp;</th><td>GA&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>HUC&emsp;</th><td>03060109&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>CLASS&emsp;</th><td>5&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>FLOW&emsp;</th><td>   26.3&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>STAGE&emsp;</th><td> 4.95&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>TIME&emsp;</th><td>2020-12-01 10:00:00&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>TIME_UTC&emsp;</th><td>2020-12-01 15:00:00&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>URL&emsp;</th><td>https://waterdata.usgs.gov/ga/nwis/uv?site_no=02198690&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>DATUM&emsp;</th><td>NAD83&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>COUNT&emsp;</th><td> 3vdssDcvSDCs0&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>PERCENTILE&emsp;</th><td>47.56&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>FLOODSTAGE&emsp;</th><td>0&emsp;</td></tr></table></div>"
[5] "<div class='scrollableContainer'><table class= id='popup'><tr><td></td><th>STAID&emsp;</th><td>02323000&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>STANAME&emsp;</th><td>SUWANNEE RIVER NEAR BELL, FLORIDA&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>ST&emsp;</th><td>FL&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>HUC&emsp;</th><td>03110205&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>CLASS&emsp;</th><td>5&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>FLOW&emsp;</th><td> 5020.0&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>STAGE&emsp;</th><td> 7.04&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>TIME&emsp;</th><td>2020-12-01 10:00:00&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>TIME_UTC&emsp;</th><td>2020-12-01 15:00:00&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>URL&emsp;</th><td>https://waterdata.usgs.gov/fl/nwis/uv?site_no=02323000&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>DATUM&emsp;</th><td>NAD83&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>COUNT&emsp;</th><td> 4vdssDcvSDCs5&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>PERCENTILE&emsp;</th><td>52.62&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>FLOODSTAGE&emsp;</th><td>0&emsp;</td></tr></table></div>"
[6] "<div class='scrollableContainer'><table class= id='popup'><tr><td></td><th>STAID&emsp;</th><td>01638500&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>STANAME&emsp;</th><td>POTOMAC RIVER AT POINT OF ROCKS, MD&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>ST&emsp;</th><td>MD&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>HUC&emsp;</th><td>02070008&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>CLASS&emsp;</th><td>5&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>FLOW&emsp;</th><td> 4940.0&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>STAGE&emsp;</th><td> 2.18&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>TIME&emsp;</th><td>2020-12-01 10:45:00&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>TIME_UTC&emsp;</th><td>2020-12-01 15:45:00&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>URL&emsp;</th><td>https://waterdata.usgs.gov/md/nwis/uv?site_no=01638500&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>DATUM&emsp;</th><td>NAD83&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>COUNT&emsp;</th><td>125&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>PERCENTILE&emsp;</th><td>50.94&emsp;</td></tr><tr><td></td><th>FLOODSTAGE&emsp;</th><td>0&emsp;</td></tr></table></div>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either achieve this by plain regex replace or by using a the `htmltools::tags$a` function that'll create the tag :

```r
str_replace_all(tables, "(https?://.+?)(?=<)", "<a href=\\\"\\1\\\">\\1</>")

str_replace_all(tables, "https?://.+?(?=<)", function(.x) as.character(htmltools::tags$a(.x, href=.x)))
```